# How to add a string after a particular character in another string in java?

Tags: java, string

I have a file with a big list of strings which is of the form

```
key1=value1  
key2=value2  
...
```

I need to add a string for eg. `(Long)` after every equal sign. And create a new file with these new strings:

```
key1=(Long)value1.
key2=(Long)value2.
...
```

How to implement this with a java program?

Comment: Search for `=` and replace it by `=(Long)`. Look in the methods of class `String` for usefule methods that you can use for this.

Comment: Or you could do this in one line with awk. `awk -F= '{ print $1"=(Long)"$2 }' bigfile`

Comment: Might I suggest using the Apache StringUtils `replace` over the default java `replace` if you can?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new FileInputStrem(file));

while(b.readLine() != null) {
     System.out.println(line.replace("=", "=(Long)"));
}

b.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
"key1=value1".replace("=", "=(Long)");
```

respectively:

```
"key1=value1".replace("=", "=" + String.valueOf(123l));
```

This will only work in Java >1.4 and if no `=` could be in the `key` or `value`

Answer (score 0):

```
public class StringReplace
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        String str1 = "key1=value";
        String rep = "=(Long)";

        //Printing Current String
        System.out.println(str1);

        //Replacing the String
        str1 = str1.replaceAll("=", rep);

        //Printing new value
        System.out.println(str1);
    }
}
```

Use `replaceAll()` or `replace()` to replace all the matches found.

The above is the easiest way. You can go with loops checking for matches as well. But it will take lot of memory,  if you are checking for lot of matches, it will be a panic.

Comment: You don't really need a `replaceAll` here. Simply using `str1.replace` would suffice.

Comment: @RohitJain: I believe it is using an algorithm which uses less memory

Comment: The only difference between them is, `replaceAll` takes `regex` as parameter, whereas, `replace` does simple string replacement. You can also look into their source code for implementations.